# ASP.NET how to generate document link for one time use

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

In my ASP.NET Web application I want users to provide a document download link which can be used only once.
If user tries to copy paste the link and open second time, the document should not be opened/found.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: one way is to set a bit and change it once its viewed. This can be checked during Page load event of the link.

Comment: A simple solution is to add some unique identifier to the link, e.g. `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` and keep a list of active identifiers on the server. Once user opens the link, you can check active IDs list and if users' link is not there - show message that the link was expired; otherwise just return the file user is asking.

Comment: if the link is not bind to a .net project ,,, it's a just a link to download a picture is there a way from IIS to make it one time use?